# RSA_private_decrypt error code : error0407106b: lib(4):funct:(113):reason(107)

Tags: c, unix, openssl, rsa

i've occourred in this error using RSA_private_decrypt:

> error0407106b: lib(4):funct:(113):reason(107)

what does it means?
and why i have this error only if i work on the net, and not if i work on localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ERR_error_string` to get a more descriptive error message like so:

```
ERR_load_crypto_strings();
ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", err);
```

Make sure you include `<openssl/err.h>` as well.